# Left of .begin must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++

I am definitely new to C++ and since the professor in the University is teaching me C atm, but I just learn C++ on my own (actually trying to mix the speed of C and the utility of C++).
This is kinda hard... And here comes something I can't handle for sure..

The following code is a part of much bigger program, but I've decided to write this tiny part only to show you the errors, the way they happen ( These are all of them, but lots more.. since the program is bigger )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>


typedef struct stud 
{ 
    std::string name;
    unsigned int fak_no;

    struct b_date 
    {
        int M;
        int D;
        unsigned Y;
    };

    std::string adm_gr;
    std::vector <float> grades;
    float sum_div_2;
};

void imp_data ( std::vector <stud> imp_vec ( int x ) )
{
    printf ( " Import data for each person: \n " );

    for ( std::vector <stud>::iterator it = imp_vec.begin(); it != imp_vec.end(); it++ 
    {
        std::cout << " for person " << ( it - imp_vec.begin() ) +1 << ": " << " \n";
    std::cout << " names: ";
        std::getline (std::cin, imp_vec.at (*it).name);
    }
}

void main ()
{
    int size;

    printf ( " Number of persons: " );
    std::cin >> size;

    std::vector <stud> lads (size);
    imp_data ( lads (size) );

    system ( " pause " );
}
```

The errors I generally get are: left of... actually anything -> .at()  .begin() .end() is not a class/struct/union 
 - But how? I think the vector is atleast an union, not talking this one is of type struct.
second.. std::getline expects 3 arguments... I provided 2... lol?
and third, " term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments " at imp_data ();

Spent too much time trying to figure this out, still unsuccessful. 
I will be very grateful if anyone can help, this will boost my learning for sure..

Comment: `void imp_data ( std::vector <stud> imp_vec ( int x ) )` looks like a bad function header declaration. You don't need the `( int x )` part.

Comment: @AndreiBârsan It's worse: it's perfectly valid (so won't cause an error message from the compiler that points out the actual problem) but doesn't mean what the OP thinks it means.

Comment: @hvd: Just curious. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: @AndyG It means `imp_vec` is a pointer to a function that takes `int x` as a parameter and returns `std::vector<stud>`.

Comment: @hvd: Ahhh, didn't even think about function pointers! Thanks!

Comment: It is to be noted that the correct definition of `main` is `int main()`, *not* `void main()`.

Comment: <rant>One more thing that others have neglected to say: **Keep your code clean!! Maintain correct indentation and flush braces!!** I swear. You will ***never*** become a good programmer if you write crap that others can't read. </rant>

Comment: @Stargazer712 what do you mean.. ergh i mean I am leaving lots of spaces when i think its needed to preserve the code clean and easy to read like.. not writting std::cout<<"something"; and writting std:: << " something "; Is that bad?

Comment: And @faranwath why should i use int main() and have to possibly write 1 more code lane for return; statement and not void main() to simply make my life easier?

Comment: @Sineastra Because `void main()` is invalid, even though your compiler accepts it. You can leave out the `return 0` statement in your `main`, did you know?

Comment: @faranwath Aye, I know this. Seen very good programmers use void main (), I think got it from there. But can you explane me why void main () is incorrect?

Comment: @Sineastra Because the language's standard says so. Period.

Comment: @faranwath Awkay, thanks for the hint :)))

Comment: @Sineastra, (a) Flush braces. If you were to print off your code, you should be able to use a ruler to draw a line between every opening brace `{` and closing brace `}` in your program. Every one of those lines should be perfectly vertical and should never hit any other code. (b) Consistent indentation. Every line of code within a block should have the same amount of indentation. Every time that you introduce a new block of code with an opening brace `{`, you increase the indentation by 1. Every time that close a block of code with a closing brace `}`, decrease the indentation by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several places of improvements in your code:

- There's no need to mix `printf()` and I/O streams: `std::cout` is fine for outputting strings to the console.
- In C++ `struct Something` is just fine, no need of `typedef struct Something`.
- Use `++it` (pre-increment) for incrementing iterators (instead of `it++`; `it++` is a premature pessimization :).
- Learn to format code correctly, especially indentation.
- Do not include unnecessary headers.
- Note that in your `imp_data()` function, the `imp_vec` vector is filled by the function, and the result should be passed back to the caller, so you should pass it by (non-const) reference: `void imp_data(std::vector<stud>& imp_vec)`.
- If you use modern C++ (C++11/14), you can use `auto` (or range-based `for`) for loop iterations. At least with `auto`, you don't have to spell the long iterator type names.

See a potential improvement of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct stud { 
    std::string name;
    // ... other fields ...
};

void imp_data(std::vector<stud>& imp_vec) {
    std::cout << "Import data for each person:\n";    
    for (auto it = imp_vec.begin(); it != imp_vec.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "for person " << ((it - imp_vec.begin()) + 1) << ": " << " \n";
        std::cout << "name: ";        
        // std::cin >> it->name;
        std::getline(std::cin, it->name);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Number of persons: ";
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;

    std::vector<stud> lads(size);
    imp_data(lads);

    // Output names
    std::cout << "\nNames:\n";
    for (const auto & x : lads) {
        std::cout << x.name << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Enjoy your learning process.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is quite useful, fixed it, it seems.
Just one more thing. What's up with std::getline thing?

Comment: Why do you need `std::getline()`? Isn't `std::cin >> name` OK for you?

Comment: Well, under *name i want to take the all 3 names of the person. Separated by spaces, is that possible to input through std::cin?

Comment: No sorry, if you want space separated strings `std::cin` seems not good to me. Try with: `std::getline(std::cin, it->name);`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector <stud> imp_vec ( int x )` is not an object. `std::vector <stud> imp_vec` is. But it should really be a **reference** to the object like `std::vector <stud> & imp_vec`

You have a lot of similar typos all through your code.

Also something that you **NEED** to do, while learning C++ coding: Write small pieces of code FIRST and COMPILE them. Then you can fix syntax errors and typos easily on small changed bits of code rather than hundreds of lines all at once.

So when writing this you should have started with something like:

```
void imp_data ( std::vector <stud> imp_vec ( int x ) )
{
}


void main ()
{
    int size = 20;
    std::vector <stud> lads (size);
    imp_data ( lads (size) );
}
```

Then fix all the errors in that. Then add more code and repeat.

Comment: Just something I got soon... Writing that tons of code only wastes m time, since I do nothing actually.. Stupid of me yeah..